# Possible bug in Visual Studio when using "display:inline-block" & "line-height" together in design view

Tags: css, visual-studio-2013

CODE:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script runat="server">
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #container{
            border:4px solid red;
            box-sizing:border-box;
        }
        #block1,#block2{
            display:inline-block;
            /*float:left;*/
            vertical-align:top;
            text-align:center;
            font-size:18px;
            line-height:22px;
            width:200px;
            height:200px;
        }

        #block1{           
            background-color:ActiveBorder;
        }
        #block2{
            background-color:#808080;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="block1">
            Block 1<br />
            needs to<br />
            have a<br />
            few rows<br />
            of text<br />
            that we<br />
            can show<br />
            to our<br />
            viewers
        </div><!--
        --><div id="block2">
            Block 2
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;" />
    </div>      
</body>
</html>
```

Description:

1. Create a simple .aspx file in Visual Studio 2013
2. Create a parent container `div` with a visible border.
3. Create two child `div`s sized 200px x 200px.
4. Add the property `display:inline-block;` to the child `div`s
5. Add the `line-height` property to the child `div`s such as `line-height:22px;`.

Expected Results:
In Design-Time, the Parent Container `div` should wrap around both child `div`s

Actual results:
In design-view the Parent Container `div` will collapse behind the child `div`s
Right-click file and select "View In Browser", Parent Container `div` renders as expected

NOTES:

1. If you remove the `line-height` property the Parent Container `div` behaves normally
2. If you leave `line-height` and change `display:inline-block;` to `float:left`s and clear them the Parent Container behaves normally as well.
3. They all view normally when viewed live in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the result from this being filed as a bug report on Microsoft Connect:

---

Greetings from Microsoft Connect!

This notification was generated for feedback item: Possible bug in Visual Studio when using "display:inline-block" & "line-height" together in design view which you submitted at theMicrosoft Connect site.

Thank you for passing along this issue to us. We evaluate all the feedback our customers submit, but unfortunately we cannot fix every item that comes in. We have evaluated the issue you submitted, and at this point, we do not anticipate releasing an update for it. If the issue is blocking you from using the product, please contact our support via the Visual Studio Help and Support (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/cc136615.aspx) page on MSDN.

You may receive a general "Feedback Item Updated" notification as well, if any other changes were made by Microsoft.

Thank you for using Microsoft Connect!

Regards,

### the Microsoft Connect Team

Microsoft admitted the BUG and goes on to say they aren't interested in fixing it for a peon like myself.  This is what happens when we create work-arounds instead of reporting bugs in volume............